# How to add a dynamic content into html for sending mail in Python

Tags: python, html, email, smtplib

I am sending mail with html content using 'smtplib' in python , I want to add dynamic content to that html.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "Error Notification"
message["From"] = sender
message["To"] = sender

# Create the plain-text and HTML version of your message
html = """\
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>Hi,<br>
           <span>Something went wrong !</span><br>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
part1 = MIMEText(html, "html")

# Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
message.attach(part1)
try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message.as_string())
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Along with the above html I need to include some of my dynamic contents inside the body tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is Python you can do really awesome things with strings. Just name certain areas of the html with **special** names and then use the [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) method to replace them with whatever value you want.

```py
html = """\
    <html>
      <body>
        <p>Hi, $(name)<br>
           <span> $(error) </span><br>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
"""

html = html.replace("$(name)", "John")
html = html.replace("$(error)", "Something went wrong!")

print(html)
```

Comment: @AswathyMA Don't forget to accept my answer (It's the check sign under the vote up).

Answer (score -1):

To include the dynamic content, just get the data from your data source and concatenate them to the body of the mail as per your need.